# Combining a mono signal with a stereo signal

Tags: audio, preamp

I'm creating a stage sound system
I have already created a preamp for the microphone and led the connector through which I will feed the music. Now I need to mix music with a preamp. The problem is that the preamp works in mono and wants to keep the music in stereo.
I want to pass the sound from the microphone to the left and right channels. I need a diagram/advice on how to do this.

Comment: Why did you delete your original question: [Hardware mixing mono mic amp with stereo music](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/665694/hardware-mixing-mono-mic-amp-with-stereo-music)

Comment: I wrote it wrong and the system/admins thought I meant proffesional systems, not DIY, and they closed answers

Comment: For future reference, you *can* edit a closed question, to correct any issues with it, and then flag it for re-opening. There's no *real* need to ask a new question.

Comment: @Andyaka The other question was closed as OT. They may hope that this one will not be so treated. They could try modifying the original question. They may be aware (although it's unlikely) how seldom closed questions succeed at being reopened :-(.

Comment: IF the preamp is mono the result MUST be mono, unless you have two of them, one for each channel.  Do you have two preamps?

Comment: I only have one unfortunately. If I had two, could I feed the two preamps with the same microphone input?

Comment: You can't put stereo through a mono amp and get stereo from it.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I think it's very unlikely that a new user would be aware of how often re-open attempts are unsuccessful, so using that as an excuse here for deleting the old one and writing a new one is disingenuous. I'd also argue that the reason for the majority of those failures is that there's usually no real attempt to make an on-topic question in the edits which lead to the re-open requests, so the fact that many re-open requests fail is no excuse for not using it when the OP really does want to make a valid attempt. FWIW, I didn't read the original Q as "use of electronics"...

Comment: ... and wouldn't have closed it, but rather asked for clarification in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a simple summing problem, which can be solvedwith the classic opamp summing circuit. A summer is needed for each unique channel, so in a stereo configuration this needs two. The same mic preamp signal is fed to both summers, whilst the left and right channels are different for each summer. Note that the circuit schematic below expects a fairly low impedance source with the signal centred around 0V. A commercial implementation may include additional considerations like AC-coupling for inputs and outputs, protection, EMC filtering etc, but the basic idea is there.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnWZnR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: @TristanGorynia  The intention of you your question is still confused. This answer tells you how to do something useful, which MAY be what you want. This allows Ain + Bin to produce (A+B)amplified. You can feed this to Aout and Bout BUT while both channels will now work you will NOT have true stereo. You will have mono fed to two outputs. || If that is acceptable then your problem is solved. If you want true stereo output then this answer is not what you want, and you will need two amplifiers.

Comment: I just wanted the microphone mono signal to be fed to the left and right channels, while maintaining the stereophonic instrumental.